# Changing border-radius effect from vertical to horizontal doesn't work

Tags: css

I have a `border-radius` effect that I would like to "rotate" 90 degrees.

```
#a{
  height:55px;
  width:70px;
  border-radius:25px 25px 42px 42px / 9px 9px 35px 35px;
}
#b{
  height:70px;
  width:55px;
  border-radius:42px 25px 25px 42px / 9px 35px 35px 9px;      
}
```

I would like to use the shape of element a on the vertically aligned element b.  But if you check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mVp29/2/ you can tell that it actually makes the left edge completely straight.  What is happening and how do I fix it. Also, I do not want to use `transform:rotate(90deg);` because their is content in the elements.

This seems to be happening in both Firefox and IE and seems to happen whether I declare the values in pixels or percentages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want #a rotated 90degrees? Try:

Counter-Clockwise:

```
#b {
  height:70px;
  width:55px;
  border-radius: 9px 35px 35px 9px / 25px 42px 42px 25px;      
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mVp29/5/

Clockwise:

```
#b {
  height:70px;
  width:55px;
  border-radius:35px 9px 9px 35px / 42px 25px 25px 42px;      
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mVp29/4/

The reason for this is because the horizontal/vertical radius values are switched when you rotate 90 degrees.

Comment: I want #b to look like #a rotated 90deg not 180deg.  If you look at the fiddle the left edge of #b does not look like the top of #a.

Comment: Ah, I see. I've modified my answer.